# Knockout custom binding to dynamically enhance JQM content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, radio-button

I have re organized my question.

Firstly I have a question page, the page contains

1. Question Text
2. Choices
3. Next, Prev and Submit buttons(as applicable)

The **snippet** of the page is below

```
 <div id="questionpage" data-role="page" data-theme="c">

    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Question <span data-bind="text: current_question().queNo"></span></h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <!-- inputs -->
    <div id="inputs" data-role="content" >    
      <a id="prevbtn" href="#question" data-bind="click: $root.prev, visible: hasPrev()" data-role="button" >Prev</a>
      <a id="nextbtn" href="#question" data-bind="click: $root.next, visible: hasNext()" data-role="button">Next</a>     
      <a id="completebtn" href="#question" data-bind="click: $root.submit, visible: !hasNext()" data-role="button">Submit</a>

      <p data-bind="text: current_question().queText"></p>
      <div id="inputdiv" data-bind="with:$root.current_question, enhancedom: $root.current_question">
        <div id="radio">
            <fieldset id="radiocontrol" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="foreach:options">
                <input name="radio-options" type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $root.current_question().response, attr: {id:'rb_' + $index() }" />
                <label data-bind="attr:{for: 'rb_' + $index() }, text: $data"></label>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->    
</div><!-- /page -->
```

The questions and their choices are fetched from the server and they are bound to Viewmodel properties.
Below is the **snippet of the supporting javascript and Viewmodel** for the page

```
// Question response object
function QuestionResponse(stuId, examQueId,selAns)
{
    var self=this;
    self.Student__c=stuId;
    self.Exam_Question__c=examQueId;
    self.Selected_Answer__c=selAns;
}

// Question object
function Question()
{ 
    var self=this;
    self.response=ko.observable('');
    self.options=ko.observableArray();
}

function Question(id, queNo, queText, response, queChA, queChB, queChC, queChD, queChE)
{
    var self=this;
    self.id=id;
    self.queNo=queNo;
    self.queText=queText;
    self.response=ko.observable(response);
    self.options=ko.observableArray();
    //self.checked=ko.observableArray();

    // helper function to add an option
    self.addOption = function(option)
    {
        if (null!=option)
        {
            self.options().push(option);
        }
    }

    self.addOption(queChA);
    self.addOption(queChB);
    self.addOption(queChC);
    self.addOption(queChD);
    self.addOption(queChE);
}

function ExamViewModel()
{
    var self=this;

    // initialise variables to default observables
    self.current_question=ko.observable(new Question());
    self.current_question_no=0;
    self.email=ko.observable('Your email id');
    self.questions=ko.observableArray();
    self.studentId;

    self.errorMsg=ko.observable('');
    self.completeMsg=ko.observable('');
    self.hasPrevious=ko.observable();
    self.hasNext=ko.observable(false);
    self.hasPrev=ko.observable(false);

    // function executed when the user clicks the 'next' button
    self.next=function()
    {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "a", text: "Loading", textVisible: true });

        // advance to the next question
        self.current_question_no++;
        self.current_question(self.questions()[self.current_question_no]());

        // setup previous/next buttons
        self.hasPrev(true);
        self.hasNext(self.current_question_no<self.questions().length-1);

        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }

    // function executed when the user clicks the 'prev' button
    self.prev=function()
    {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "a", text: "Loading", textVisible: true });
        //alert('in prev '+self.current_question().response);
        self.current_question_no--;
        self.current_question(self.questions()[self.current_question_no]());
        self.hasPrev(self.current_question_no!=0);
        self.hasNext(true);
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    }

    // An AJAX call is made and this is callback for the JavaScript remoting call    
    self.responseCB=function(record, event)
    {
        if ( (!event) || (event.status) ) 
        {
            $.each(record,
                    function()
                    {
                        var question=new ko.observable(new Question(
                                                        this.Id, this.Exam_Question_Number__c, this.Question__r.Question_Text__c,'', 
                                                        this.Question__r.ChoiceA__c, this.Question__r.ChoiceB__c, this.Question__r.ChoiceC__c,
                                                        this.Question__r.ChoiceD__c,this.Question__r.ChoiceE__c));

                        self.questions.push(question);

                        // if the current question is empty, set it to this question 
                        if (typeof self.current_question().queText === 'undefined')
                        {
                            self.current_question(question());
                        }
                    });

            // setup whether to display the next button                             
            if (self.questions().length>1)
            {
                self.hasNext(true);
            }

        }
        else if (event.type === 'exception')
        {
            self.error(event.message);
        }
    }

}
    // enhancedom custom binding
    // runs jQuery Mobile on updated DOM elements
    ko.bindingHandlers.enhancedom = {
        update: function (element) {
            $(element).trigger("create");
        }
    };

    // bind event onto the display of the 'loading' page - the first stacked div (logical page)
    // this creates the viewmodel which handles the loading etc
    $( "#loadingpage" ).on( "pageshow", function() {
        if (null==viewModel)
        {         

            viewModel=new ExamViewModel();

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        }
    });
```

Given the scenario my question has 2 parts

1. Without any custom binding `enhancedom` on `<div id="inputdiv"></div>` my
   code is working perfectly fine, the choices selected by the user are
   retained across navigation and he is able to submit, but the **radio
   button choices are not JQM enhanced**.
2. In order to allow JQM enhance the radio buttons(whenever question is
   populated) I have written this custom binding `enhancedom`. In this case the
   JQM enhancement is working, but I am losing the responses the user has 
   selected on navigation.

I think I am missing something in integrating KO and JQM, I tried some options based on my research but could not figure out the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your question exactly? It seems to me the binding is just quite a ways from finished (i.e. where's the rest?). PS. It would be easier for us to help you if you make your question and code more minimal (for *example*, the `data-icon` stuff is probably irrelevant to this question) and also more complete (preferably up to the point where we have a runnable example).

Comment: @Jeroen I have made changes to my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I learnt from this [link](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2013/08/06/How-to-2-way-bind-a-jquery-mobile-flip-switch.aspx) that custom binding is only the way to let KO update the HTML before JQM enhances it. I need some help in this direction.